# CSS: First Selector

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, css-selectors

I have an `<DL>` element with groups of `<DT>` and `<DD>`

I have it currently looking like this:

```
AAAAA   111111
        222222
        333333
BBBBB   111111
        222222
        333333
```

I am trying to put space between the `<DT>` so it looks like this:

```
AAAAA   111111
        222222
        333333

BBBBB   111111
        222222
        333333
```

How do I get the CSS to apply a space between DT elements while maintaining the over all spacing?

Here's my CSS currently:

```
dl { padding: 25px 0px 25px 0px; }

dt {
    clear: left;
    float: left;
    text-align: left;
    width: 90px;
}

dd {
    margin: 0 0 0 90px;
    padding: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

the HTML is:

```
<dl>
<dt>AAAAAAA</dt>
<dd>11111111</dd>
<dd>11111111</dd>
<dd>11111111</dd>
<dd>11111111</dd>
<dd>11111111</dd>    

<dt>BBBBBBBB</dt>
<dd>11111111</dd>
<dd>11111111</dd>
<dd>11111111</dd>
<dd>11111111</dd>
<dd>11111111</dd>    
</dl>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on, "apply a space between DT elements while maintaining over all spacing?" I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: I wish to add a space between the [dt] elements, but not any other element. Just like the sample really, a nice visual space between AAAAA and BBBBB

Comment: I have added sample html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add padding or margin to the `dt` elements, plus the `dd` elements immediately after a `dt`.

Using your existing code, just add the following:

```
dt, dt+dd {
    margin-top:15px;
}
```

If you don't want the first one to have the padding, then override it on the first one with the `first-of-type` selector. Again, add the following:

```
dt:first-of-type, dt+dd:first-of-type {
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

jsFiddle example here: http://jsfiddle.net/C2FRn/

(note that `first-of-type` isn't available for IE8 or earlier; there are hacks to work around it, but if you need IE8 support, you may find it easier simply to add a class to the first `dt`, or use `dl+dt, dt+dt+dd` as the selector)

Comment: ...or you could use `dt+dd, dd+dt` as a selector for your rule - this way the very first dt will not match it. So no need for `first-of-type`

Comment: @o.v. - yep, there are a few ways to skin this cat. In the absence of needing IE8 support, I'd prefer to stick with `first-of-type` because it is semantic -- if I came back to the code in a year's time, I'd stand a chance of understanding what I'd been trying to do. The `dt+dd, dd+dt` solution is concise but would need comments to make it understandable to someone reading it what the purpose of it is.